# Is there any platform like Booking.com that accepts payments with a Maestro Card (Debit Card)?

Tags: bookings, booking.com

I've been trying to book a hotel room, I've tried with many hotels, but at the payment phase, all of them ask for payments using either Visa or MasterCard, while I have Maestro.
Can Anyone help concerning this matter? Do you know any website where there is a variety of paying methods? 
The thing is that I need that booking to present it as a proof of booking for the visa procedures!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your bank should be able to help you get a MasterCard, depending on what country you're in.

Comment: Depends on the country I think. In the Netherlands there's a (widely used) [service](https://www.ideal.nl/en/) to pay via (maestro) debit card online (on many websites, including booking.com).

Comment: May sites that say MasterCard actually also include Maestro cards (which use the same network), though this is not universal. You may want to try with your existing card and see if it’s accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried contacting the hotels directly? 
They should be able to tell you whether they accept debit cards or not, you might even get a better price for booking it directly with them.
On the Booking.com website there's a section with payment options all the way at the bottom of the listing.

Most hotels require a credit card as they'll place a hold on your card for the cost of 1 night in case you're a no-show.

At the end of the day it's at the hotel's discretion which payment methods they accept.

You could also check if the hotel accepts PayPal and link your debit card to a PayPal account.
According to the [Booking.com customer support page](https://secure.booking.com/content/cs.en-gb.html) (Find information -> Payment -> What payment methods are accepted?) some locations do indeed offer PayPal as an accepted payment method.